# Wrapping My Head Around await async and NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, async-await

Given this code:

```
private ISession _session;

public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(int id) where T : ISomeEntity
{
    //how to call and return _session.Get<T>(id) asynchronous
}
```

Is it possible to call NHibernate `ISession.Get<T>()` asynchronously? Advisable? Not worth it?

Comment: NHibernate does support async operations now: http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2017/12/11/nhibernate-async-support/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

NHibernate does not support Async await in the sense of entity framework does by default. However it would be recommended to do so (if you could) since a database call is an IO call which is a very good candidate to make it async. As a result while waiting response from DB your thread will return to the pool instead of being pend and it will make your app more scalable. 
Now coming to async support. I have forked NHibernate to achive this. 
In my fork which I call NHibernateX, there are Async Methods like GetAsync, ListAsync, ToListAsync etc
Here's the source and nuget package:

https://github.com/ReverseBlade/nhibernate-core

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NHibernateX/

Comment: Hi, I have pulled down the NHibernateX library and was looking through it. I was wondering if you happen to have any examples to share so I may be able to get some better ideas on how to put this to use. Thanks!

Comment: @MattB see this API changes, https://github.com/OnurGumus/nhibernate-core/commit/ef67c54724c24ce44915805331dd4af25917f15a

Comment: for what it's worth, NHibernate now supports async / await (since 2017): https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/nhibernate-async-support/

Answer (score 8):

If the underlying operation ins't already asynchronous in some way (i.e. `async-await`, `BeginXXX`/`EndXXX`, etc.) there's no value in adding an `async` wrapper around it.

`async` is useful in 2 cases: scalability and responsiveness. Doing *`async` over sync* doesn't help with scalability at all and for responsiveness you can simply use `Task.Run` to offload that work to another `ThreadPool` thread when you need instead of adding a dedicated method.

More in [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx)

Comment: Even Async Await would offload the execution to a thread pool, isn't that a better mechanism than using Task, which offloads from the beginning of the method. In this case it can be synchronous till it doesn't take much time and aynchronous from the point await is used

Comment: @MrinalKamboj async-await doesn't offload to the `ThreadPool`. All the `async` keyword does is let you use `await` inside the method, and there's nothing to `await` here.

Comment: On using await in a method marked with async, aren't we off the context of main thread / calling thread, then it has to be a separate thread. In fact return for Async methods is mostly Task<T>. Interesting part is post await it switches back to the context of main / calling thread like UI

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Before the first `await` the execution is on the calling thread. After the `await` you're usually either on a `ThreadPool` thread or the UI thread. What matters is what happens between. While a (truly) `async` operations is being executed there is no thread at all.

Here however, there's no task to `await`. You can create one with `Task.Run` but that would be blocking a `ThreadPool` thread throughout the entire operation.

Comment: Async is better than just Task.Run for responsiveness because it can marshal code back onto the UI thread later with explicitly having to write .NET 4.0 style continuations. Though of course you can `await` the results of `Task.Run` when appropriate.

Comment: @JonathanAllen `async` here means an async wrapper, which there's no reason to add. Of course if you use `Task.Run` directly from UI code you can await it if that makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

[NHibernate 5 now support the pattern](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/releases/tag/5.0.0)

```
private ISession _session;

public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(int id) where T : ISomeEntity
{
    return await _session.GetAsync<T>(id);
}
```