# C# EF6: Two navigation properties of the same type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Simply, in C# EF6, how do you map two navigation properties to the same table while keeping their result sets separate? In plain English, I have a class that I want two collections of in another class. In other words, I want two collections of the same type but with different elements. Unfortunately, EF6 seems to treat both collections the same and gives them both the same elements (every record in the table).

The best I found from dozens of StackOverflow answers was this, but it has the problem described. In this example, a **Father** has many **Sons** and many **Daughters**, and they each have the one **Father**. Ideally, both **Sons** and **Daughters** can be stored in the same table **Child**.

```
class Father
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Sons { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Daughters { get; set; }
}

class Child
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long FatherId_1 { get; set; }  

    public Father Father_1 { get; set; }

    public long FatherId_2 { get; set; }  // One for each collection???

    public Father Father_2 { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.Father_1)
            .WithMany(e => e.Sons)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.FatherId_1);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.Father_2)
            .WithMany(e => e.Daughters)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.FatherId_2);
}
```

The problem with this is, when reading the data back from the **Child** table, it doesn't discriminate between **Sons** and **Daughters**. That is, the **Sons** collection will not only contain **Sons** but also **Daughters**, and so will the **Daughters** collection. I might have expected EF6 to try to use a discriminator column, but it doesn't.

**Question:** How do you map two navigation properties to the same table and still be able to read its records back into their corresponding navigation properties? Or, is the example correct, and my problem is elsewhere? Or, is this not possible, and they need to be mapped to their own tables (with identical schemas).

Answer (score 1):

I am a little confused, with your explanation. But I found some code for what I understand:

For "It's one model "Child" that needs to be split into two collections" :

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
.Map(m =>
  {
    m.Properties(t => new { t.Id /*other props*/ });
    m.ToTable("Sons");
  })
.Map(m =>
  {
    m.Properties(t => new { t.Id /*other props*/});
    m.ToTable("Daughters");
  });
```

Comment: It's one model "Child" that needs to be split into two collections, not two models that need to be stored in one table. Why would you create two classes for the same logical type in your model? Can you show how you would solve the above problem in code?

Comment: If I'm reading that right, it maps some properties to one table and other properties to another table. Is that right? I clarified my problem in the first paragraph. Basically, I have a class that I want to have two collections of in another class. This seems like it would be a common pattern. I'm confused why there's little information on it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this problem by using a [domain object backed by a state object](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=879). Basically, you use a state object to store the data the way EF likes, and your domain object is what exposes that data to the rest of your application. For example:

```
public class Father
{
    //--- Constructor ---

    internal Father(FatherState state)
    {
        State = state;
    }

    //--- Properties ---

    public long Id => State.Id;

    public IList<Child> Sons => Children.Where(child => child.Type == ChildType.Son).ToList().AsReadOnly();

    public IList<Child> Daughters => Children.Where(child => child.Type == ChildType.Daughter).ToList().AsReadOnly();

    //--- Methods ---

    public void AddChild(Child child)
    {
        State.Children.Add(child);
    }

    public void RemoveChild(Child child)
    {
        State.Children.Remove(child);
    }
}

internal class FatherState
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long FatherId { get; set; }  

    public Father Father { get; set; }

    public ChildType Type { get; set; }
}

public enum ChildType
{
    Son,
    Daughter
}
```

Of course, this can only be used with the repository pattern because it has to translate the `FatherState` object provided by EF into the `Father` object consumed by the application.

I think the real solution is to switch to a [fully featured ORM like NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998609/entity-framework-vs-nhibernate-performance/39957599#39957599). EF is far too underdeveloped, and that's only gotten worse with .NET Core. I don't even see how it's possible to do proper DDD with EF. A lot of developers must be compromising on their models. NHibernate has a lot of advantages, and the only caveat I've found is it doesn't provide async methods, but there's [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30129665/404566) or [two](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3971?focusedCommentId=49911&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-49911) arguments to made against it, and it [can be done anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18638346/404566). There's also [forks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30173860/404566) of NHibernate that provide them as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't require separate mappings altogether to bifurcate same FatherId for Son and daughter. The better solution is to make a unique identifier in `Child Table` like `enum` as previous answer suggests or add a `Gender` field in your `Child` model and keep only one mapping of `Father` model. (I don't know your exact requirements, but `Father`, `Child` can also be generalized in one super class `human` or `person` in strict Object Oriented terms).

But since I am not sure of your requirements, if you really want to continue with your mapping then the solution I propose is this.

```
  class Father
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public int SonId{get;set;}
        public int DaughterId{get;set;}


        [ForeignKey("SonId")]
        public virtual Child Child_Son{get;set;}

        [ForeignKey("DaughterId")]
        public virtual Child Child_Son{get;set;}
    }

    class Child
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public string Gender{get;set;}
    }
```

**Explanation**:

Two foreign keys each for `Son` and `Daughter` of same `Child` class in `Father` class will easily help you achieve separate collections using basic Linq or any sql query. Moreover, This preserves the rule "If parent exists only then child exists".

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and report back.

Comment: I had trouble implementing it, but I cannot confirm or deny it. I might have gotten it to work if I tried longer. I'm short on time and settled on mapping all records to a single ICollection property, then I use accessor properties to divide and sort the results (similar to my answer). It keeps my database design clean, and the code easy to understand.

Comment: The child class suppose to have fatherId while the Father class should have the collection of children. add public virtual ICollection<Child> children {get; set;} to Father class.

Answer (score 0):

What I could see in your modeling is that, the child entity needs to have property fatherId and gender. Check the code below:

```
public class Child
{
   [Key]
   public long Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public Gender Gender{get; set;} //Usually use Enum containing Female and Male
   public long FatherId{get; set;}

   public virtual Father Father {get; set;}
}

public class Father
{
  public Father()
  {
     Children = new HashSet<Child>();
  }  

  [Key]
  public long Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}

  public virtual ICollection<Child> Children{get; set;}
}
```

Getting child base on gender will work for what you want to do.